# How to read json file without using python loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file that I want to convert into DataFrame. Since the dataset is pretty large (~30 GB), I found that I need to set the chunksize as the limitation. The code is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows

datas = pd.read_json('/Users/xxxxx/Downloads/Books.json', chunksize = 1, lines = True)

datas
```

Then when I run it the result is

```
<pandas.io.json._json.JsonReader at 0x15ce38550>
```

Is this an error?

Also I found that if you use loop in the `datas`, it worked. Is there any way to use the standard way?

Comment: No, it's not an error, it's just a class instance.

Comment: If you look at the [source] for `read_json`, you'll see that it creates a `JsonReader`.  If you provide a `chunksize`, it returns that reader.  Otherwise it returns `jsonreader.read()`.  For more of an over view, try https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/io.html#reading-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think pandas is the way to go when reading giant json files.

First you should check out if your file is actually in a valid JSON format (it is completely wrapped in one dictionary) or if it is a JSONL file (each row is one dictionary in JSON format but the rows are not connected).

Because if you are e.g. using the Amazon Review Dataset which has these huge files they are all in JSONL but named JSON.

Two packages I can recommend for parsing huge JSON/JSONL files:

Pretty fast: [ujson](https://pypi.org/project/ujson/)

```
import ujson
with open(file_path) as f:
    file_contents = ujson.load(f)
```

Even faster: [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/)

```
import ijson
file_contents = [t for t in ijson.items(open(file_path), "item")]
```

This allows you to use a progress bar like [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/2.2.3/) as well:

```
import ijson
from tqdm import tqdm
file_contents = [t for t in tqdm(ijson.items(open(file_path), "item"))]
```

This is good to know how fast it is going as it shows you how many lines it already read. Since your file is 30GB it might take quite a while to read it all and it's good to know if its still going or the memory crashed or w/e else could have gone wrong.

You can then try to create a DataFrame from the dictionary by using `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(file_contents)` but I think 30GB of contents is way more than pandas allows as maximum number of rows. Not quite sure though. Generally I would really recommend working with dictionaries for this amount of content as it's much faster. Then only when you need to display some parts of it for visualization or analysis convert it into a DataFrame.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer @ewz93 . I did follow your instruction to use ijson and tqdm but now the result is  `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`, is this mean something?

Comment: This is probably because of the import of `tqdm`. I wrote it wrong in my code. You have to use: `from tqdm import tqdm`. Because tqdm is an object wrapper and not a module, so if you just import the module you load the file but cant call it. I corrected it in the answer now.

Comment: Yeah, I found that that is the problem. After searching the answer here and there for the problems that come up, I finally can print the data in the JSON format with your way so I guess your answer solved the problem. But IDK why I can only print one data only. Anyway, thank you for your help! Appreciate it.

Comment: The content of `file_contents` is only a list comprehension iterator, so it allows for is a sequential access to the elements but not for random access. You can e.g. use `for item in file_contents: ...`, but you can not use `file_contents[1]`. You would have to load it entirely into a list in memory to get full access like a normal list (use `list(file_contents)` around it). But then whatever you do would probably get a memory crash unless you have 30GB or more of RAM on your computer, because the entire data would have to be loaded into memory.

Comment: The advantage of the list comprehension is it does not load into memory. Only creates an "access sequence" object that you can use for iteration and then when you call or iterate over it the individual elements are actually loaded.